# Picking random ETH address

Tags: ether, addresses

This question is not specific to Solidity but in general - if i would like to randomly pick some existing ETH address, how should i do that? For example, i wanna send some token to random ETH address, but only existing one. What would be the proper way of doing that?

Comment: All addresses exist. Do you mean an address that has been used in the past, and which now has a non-zero balance?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all accounts with the help of parity. It enables this feature by the RPC call to [parity_listaccounts](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module.html#parity_listaccounts).

This feature is also available in geth, but that question still needs a proper answer.

Here is the question I am talking about: [List all ethereum accounts using geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45644/list-all-ethereum-accounts-using-geth)