# List all ethereum accounts using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, accounts

Etherscan displays all accounts in ethereum being used in the following section https://etherscan.io/accounts

**Question:** How can I get a list of all active ethereum accounts using geth?

**Possible answer:** Use Parity. It enables this feature by the RPC call to [parity_listaccounts](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module.html#parity_listaccounts).

**Why Not an answer:** The account information is available at https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/accounts and rinkeby runs only geth. So geth must be able to provide this information.

### Update

**A similar question:** There exists a similar question [How to list ALL Ethereum addresses with a positive balance](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/27809/16048), but that requires traversing each block which is very time costly process.

Comment: are you running a fully sinchronized Ethereum node ? If so, it is possible. with a simple code

Comment: @Nulik But that simple code would take eternity ;)

Comment: @Ayushya, why eternity?

Comment: Traversing each block and analyzing txs is slow.

Comment: @Ayushya, I am not talking about reprocessing the whole blockchain from genesis block, you can get the last state with a single call and print it to file

Comment: @Nulik I think thats exactly what I want to do, can you post an answer.

Comment: @Ayushya, if you don't have a full node in sync with the network it won't help

Comment: @Nulik if having a full node is a requirement, you can mention that in the answer

Comment: @Nulik I am looking for the solution, not worried about what it takes to get there.

Comment: when you get full node, let me know

Comment: @Nulik am doing this on my private network so I am in full control of it.

Comment: well, then, when my node syncs fully I will post my answer with the data and code.

Comment: @Nulik can we not confirm it with some private test network?

Answer (score -2):

From command line using CLI in order of creation : `$ geth account list`
When using the console : `> eth.accounts`

Comment: This lists only those accounts whose keystore files are present with us. It does not list _all_ accounts